# ft_min_word_len=3 no match with three characters

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-administration

I have an InnoDB-table where searches with three character-words don't work. I found that there is a possibility to change the *ft_min_word_len* option in the [mysqld]-section of the my.cnf file. The option was not there by default, so I entered it with the value 3.

```
ft_min_word_len=3
```

Then I restarted the whole server and rebuilt the indexes:

```
mysqldump mydatabase > dump.sql
mysql mydatabase < dump.sql
```

When I check the settings in phpMyAdmin

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len'
```

It shows me that the setting is correct. I even created a index on the specific field.
But I don' retrieve any results for words with three chars. Do I oversee something?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: can you provide some example of data you are searching for ?

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with PHP.

Comment: ft_min_word_len is only for fulltext-searches. What does your query look like? Mabye a stopword-issue?

Comment: @Abhik: I search for Titles like "AMI Marktbilanz Obst (49a68)". Here the search returns no results. Curios is that when I search for "MI Marktbilanz Obst (49a68)" I get a result - both time without any quotation marks.

Comment: @Marc: First I had the impression that it has to do with stopwords beacuse I first noticed it with articles later I found out that all three character words don't work

Answer (score 3):

The setting for the InnoDB fulltext is called `innodb_ft_min_token_size`.
`ft_min_word_len` is for MyISAM.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html